bash - check free available space against requered
in bash i will run a script that take a look in the folder folder123/ to know how much space is requered for the files they are in there.
but this requered value will i multiplie with 1,5 and than subtract from the space they are available is at .
if there are enough available space than go on in the script, but if not exit with an error.
for checking how much space is requered i try this
du -b folder123/ | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'
for checking how much space is available, i find out this
df --output=avail -B 1 "$PWD" |tail -n 1
but how to multiplie the requered with 1,5 and than to subtract from the available, in bash-script?
:edit
if i use something like
avail=$(df --output=avail -B 1 . | tail -n 1)
req=$(( $(du -sb tempdir/ | cut -f1) * 3 / 2))
sum=$(printf '%d\n' "$((avail - req))")

but how than to go on to check if $sum are oke?

BTW if you want to store the difference you don’t need printf: diff=$((avail - req))

Store the available bytes in a variable:
avail=$(df --output=avail -B 1 . | tail -n 1)

Do the same with the required bytes, and multiply by 3/2 (bash doesn’t support floating point arithmetic):
req=$(( $(du -sb folder123 | cut -f1) * 3 / 2))

The difference is then available as
printf '%d\n' "$((avail - req))"

To make a decision based on the values, compare them; for example
if (( req > avail )); then
    printf 'Not enough storage, %s available but %s required\n' "$avail" "$req"
    exit 1
fi

